# sed won't remove instances of multi-line string from file

Tags: bash, sed

I am attempting to remove all instances of a string that takes up multiple lines. Here's an excerpt from the file i'm trying to manipulate:

```
xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 90 32
xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 270 32; xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 180 2
xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 90 32
xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 270 32; xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 180 2
```

The end result is supposed to look like this:

```
mousemove_relative --sync --polar 180 2
mousemove_relative --sync --polar 180 2
```

Here is the code I made to do this:

```
width=16
sed -i -e 's/xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 90 '$(($width * 2))''\n'xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 270 '$(($width * 2))'; //g' file.sh
```

However, running this code does nothing to the target file. I've checked the syntax and done some searching, and I can think of any reason why this wouldn't work. Perhaps I'm not using the right tool for the job. Any insight into why this doesn't work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` works on a line at a time by default. Try using the `N` command to read two lines at a time like this:

```
sed -e '{
    N
    s/xdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 90 32\nxdotool mousemove_relative --sync --polar 270 32; //g
    P
    D
}' file.sh
```

Here's how it works with a simpler example file (`test.file`):

```
Line A
Line B
Line C
Line D
```

To replace `Line B` and `Line C` you run:

```
sed -e '{
    N
    s/Line B\nLine C/New Line B and C/g
    P
    D
}' test.file
```

`sed` will:

- Read `Line A`.
- `N` command reads in the next line so the buffer is `Line A\nLine B`.
- The `s/../../g` find and replace is applied to the buffer.
- `P` command prints the first line the buffer.
- `D` command pops off the first line in the buffer.
- And the next `N` command appends another line.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 's/.* xdotool //p' file.sh
```

Output:

```
mousemove_relative --sync --polar 180 2
mousemove_relative --sync --polar 180 2
```